# Extjs 4: use ux.center

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, javascript-framework

I'm having trouble using the custom layout ux.center. Am I doing the Ext.Loader or the Ext.require wrong? The Center.js file is under /var/www/application/ux/layout/Center.js and this file (app.js) is under /var/wwww/application/app.js

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', '/var/www/application/ux');
Ext.require('Ext.ux.layout.Center');
Ext.application({
    name: 'AM',
    appFolder: 'app',
    controllers: ['Users'],
    launch: function(){
            Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(Ext.create('Ext.state.CookieProvider'));
            Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
                    width: 1150,
                    height: 'auto',
                    autoScroll: 'true',
                    layout: 'anchor',
                    items:[{xtype: 'userpanel'},
                    {
                            xtype: 'panel',
                            width: 1150,
                            layout:'ux.center',
                            items:[{ 
                                    xtype: 'panel',
                                    width: 1150,
                                    widthRatio: .75,
                                    items: [{
                                            xtype: 'userbutton',
                                            action: '',
                                            text: 'Print'
                                    },
                                    {
                                            xtype: 'userbutton',
                                            action: '',
                                            text: 'Download'
                                    },
                                    {
                                            xtype: 'userbutton',
                                            action: 'chart',
                                            text: 'Chart!'
                                    }]
                            }]}]
            });
}});
```

Thank you for any tips on getting this layout to work

Comment: Could you be more specific? "Having trouble" doesn't really tell us anything useful.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its not being included right. The page doesn't load at all when I try to use it as a layout. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should run Ext.application method after extjs loads /var/www/application/ux/layout/Center.js script. To do this, just add a callback using Ext.onReady

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', '/var/www/application/ux');
Ext.require('Ext.ux.layout.Center');

Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.application({ ... });
});
```

But the right way is using "requires" configuration property

```
Ext.application({
    requires: ['Ext.ux.layout.Center'],
    name: 'AM',
    appFolder: 'app',        
    controllers: ['Users'],
    launch: function(){
            Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(Ext.create('Ext.state.CookieProvider'));
            Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
                    width: 1150,
                    height: 'auto',
                    autoScroll: 'true',
                    layout: 'anchor',
                    items:[{xtype: 'userpanel'},
                    {
                            xtype: 'panel',
                            width: 1150,
                            layout:'ux.center',
                            items:[{ 
                                    xtype: 'panel',
                                    width: 1150,
                                    widthRatio: .75,
                                    items: [{
                                            xtype: 'userbutton',
                                            action: '',
                                            text: 'Print'
                                    },
                                    {
                                            xtype: 'userbutton',
                                            action: '',
                                            text: 'Download'
                                    },
                                    {
                                            xtype: 'userbutton',
                                            action: 'chart',
                                            text: 'Chart!'
                                    }]
                            }]}]
            });
}});
```

Also you can read following material http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application

You can also create your own class for viewport and put it in the [appFolder]/view/ folder

```
Ext.define('AM.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.view.Viewport',

    requires: ['Ext.ux.layout.Center'],

    width: 1150,
    height: 'auto',
    autoScroll: 'true',
    layout: 'anchor',

    initComponent: function () {
        this.items = [{
            xtype: 'userpanel'
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            width: 1150,
            layout:'ux.center',
            items:[{ 
                xtype: 'panel',
                width: 1150,
                widthRatio: .75,
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'userbutton',
                    action: '',
                    text: 'Print'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'userbutton',
                    action: '',
                    text: 'Download'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'userbutton',
                    action: 'chart',
                    text: 'Chart!'
                }]
            }]
        }];
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

And use Ext.app.Application config property **autoCreateViewport**. It will load [appFolder]/view/Viewport.js script and use it as viewport

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'AM',
    appFolder: **insert you app folder path here**, // in you case it will be 'application'       
    controllers: ['Users'],
    autoCreateViewport: true
});
```

Comment: Hi tramway,
Thanks for the suggestions, I'm going to keep messing around with it. So far it doesn't like the require statement in the application declaration. I don't see that as a config property in the sencha docs for Ext.app.application